# NHibernate.QueryException with what appears to be a simple query expression

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

We're attempting to implement the specification pattern in our DAL but are running into some problems.  It appears that NHibernate is unable to transform the expression into something usable, but I'm not 100% certain if that is the issue.

I have a customer object that contains a social security number object that in turn contains a property called LastSegment that simply returns the last four digits of the ssn.  In creating a specification that searches against the last segment of a ssn, we came up with the following expression where value is the search criteria passed in by the user:

```
a => a.Customer.Ssn.LastSegment == value
```

Seems fairly simple.  However, when this is run, an exception is throw with the following error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: Ssn.LastSegment of: [namespace].Customer
```

Am I interpreting the error correctly in that NHibernate cannot translate my expression into something it can use?  Is there any way to get around this?

As a further note, we also get this error when we call `ToString()` on some objects.

EDIT:
Digging into the SocialSecurityNumber object, I noticed it is a struct instead of a class.  Could that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LastSegment is a property that you added in a partial class. You won't be able to use that in your nhibernate expression. You will need to change your `where` expression to use the actual property that is mapped to your database (Whatever `LastSegment` is referencing).

If `Segment` is a string you might be able to do something like this:

```
a => a.Customer.Ssn.Segment.SubString(someNumber, 4) == value
```

Comment: LastSegment actually returns the last 4 digits of the property UnformattedValue.  However, if I change my expression to UnformattedValue.EndsWith(value).  It still blows up saying it could not resolve property: Ssn.UnformattedValue.

Comment: @Brian - what is the type of UnformattedValue? If it is a string with a set number of characters you can use SubString

Comment: UnformattedValue is just a string: public string UnformattedValue

Comment: I think I've found another piece of info that may be useful.  The Ssn is stored in the database as a string.  I believe this is being accomplished with a custom UserType.  If I'm not mistaken, the custom usertype allows us to store the SocialSecurityNumber object as a string and retrieve the string as a SocialSecurityNumber object.  This appears to be the smoking gun, but I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: @Brian - Have you tried the SubString approach? if the length is more than 3 characters you can do something like this: `a.Customer.Ssn.SubString(a.Customer.Ssn.length-4, 4) == value`

Comment: I can't call Substring bc Ssn is a custom class instead of a string.

Comment: @Brian - Does Ssn contain a string property?

Comment: It has all kinds of strings in it: UnformattedValue, LastSegment, FirstSegment, etc.  But anytime I reference them I get the "could not resolve property" error.